# new SBS 2011 Standard problems

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

Brand new SBS 2011 install. I went to remove the DHCP server role. It went into a "Preparing to configure Windows. Do not turn off your computer." Been there for hours. Finally, decided to power off and restart. After boot up, the same window and message appear and it just sits there spinning. "Preparing to configure Windows. Do not turn off your computer." I'd love to get this installed before the end of the day but it doesn't look like that's possible. Any ideas on how to get passed this?

Comment: I had a similar issue a few years ago with SBS 2008. see the answers I got here: http://serverfault.com/questions/35328/server-2008-stuck-in-update-configure-fail-restart-loop